# Generics using Macro expansion: Why the poor use of Instruction cache?

Tags: c++, generics, compiler-construction

Russ Cox (Go core dev) on his [blog](https://research.swtch.com/generic) on generic implementations mentioned following about the macro expansion(C++) method to implement generics -

> The individual specializations may be efficient but the program as a
>   whole can suffer due to poor use of the instruction cache

I have been thinking about this statement for days but fail to understand the reason behind it. Is there any sound reason behind this assumption?

I understand that the instruction cache will not be used well(relatively) if we have -

1. A poor locality of reference of instructions
2. A poor branch prediction.

Does macro expansion causes any of these?

**Update**: Similar discussion in [Go Generic Discussion Summary](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vrAy9gMpMoS3uaVphB32uVXX4pi-HnNjkMEgyAHX4N4/view#heading=h.6cuzjb7v9wrw). Here they generalised the technique used in C++ as *Type Specialization*

Comment: Templates are not macro. These are two distinct language features. Are you sure you want to ask about macros here? "*Specializations*" usually refers to specializations of a template, not expansions of a macro.

Comment: In C++ macros and templates are two *very* different things.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I will change it

Comment: C++ templates have more kinship to Lisp macros than to the C preprocessor macros.  Contextually, calling them "macros" is confusing.  C++ templates are compile-time code generators, but as a sublanguage were not designed to be used that way so the syntax is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of a template is effectively a separate class. If you use a `std::vector<int>` and a `std::vector<float>` you end up with two complete copies of the vector implementation (most standard libraries try to move as much code as possible out of the vector into a base class or private implementation class for this reason but some duplication remains). With (up to)twice as much code being used the instruction caches will fill twice as fast.

Comment: So is it as same as having a huge code (forget generics here), so more instructions man more data going to cache? But then again, with temporal and spacial locality it should be ok intuitively. 

Because I would be using either vector<int> or vector <float>. If I use both, they will be completely different classes, which is the same case with go

Comment: It might be worth mention that if some code have two instances of `std::vector<int>` (e.g. `std::vector<int> va; std::vector<int> vb;`) then this "doubling" of the code doesn't happen, because there's only one `std::vector<int>` class.

Comment: Yup, true, that will be two instances of same class

Comment: @MangatRaiModi I think the point is that generics let you generate a lot of code without realizing it. You type `std::map<int, string>` and if that's the only `std::map<int, string>` in your program, you just generated a ton of code for a one-time variable. Without generics, you would be more inclined to find opportunities to reuse existing code. Maybe somebody else has written a `char -> string` dictionary, so you'll upgrade the dictionary to `int -> string` and the other person can switch to that. If both maps are used at the same time, then this improves I-cache.